# exists (u,v) edge with positive capacity and there is not path from $s$ to $u$. and $(u,v)$ is with full capacity in some maximal flow.

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

> Given a network flow and there exists (u,v) edge with positive capacity and there is not path from $s$ to $u$. and $(u,v)$ is with full capacity in some maximal flow.

I've had this questions with true or false and I thought it was false but apparently it is true.
Can someone please explain me how this is possible?

Comment: How can the $(u,v)$ edge have positive capacity if there is no path from $s$ to $u$? The flow has to get there somehow.

Comment: That's what I thought..